# Slide in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to jQuery. I have learned functions like SlideUp and Down but I can't find anything like Slide Left and Right.

I want to make a content slide with horizontal sliding effects. I have achieved vertical sliding in it. I dont want to use an existing plugin or library. I want to build my own.

Please guide me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here**](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions) is a great tutorial to slide elements in different directions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/HH3h7/1/) using `animate()`. This can easily be adpoted to be a jQuery function rather than JS functions

```
$('#slidein').click(function(){
    $('div').stop().animate({
        'width':'500px'
    }, 500);
});

$('#slideout').click(function(){
    $('div').stop().animate({
        'width':'0px'
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `animate()` function as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to adjust the `width` property of the element you want to animate.

There are a number of examples on that page so you should be able to play with what's there to achieve your desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe JCycle can be suitable for you. It supports a lot of changing slide such as up, down, left, right, fade in/out, ....

You can download and view demo at this website : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/